# WordPress API passing email argument issue

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

Using a WordPress REST API custom endpoint, I am attempting to get user data (or at least the user id) with the following code in the functions.php file:

```
    function getUser(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    global $wpdb;
    $email = $request->get_param( 'email' );    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = $email";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $result;
}


    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myapi/v1', '/getcustomer/(?P<email>[^/]+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getUser'
        ) );
    } );
```

Testing the function with the endpoint /wp-json/myapi/v1/getcustomer/joe@anymail.com it returns with empty brackets `[ ]`. Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You should encode your user emails or send it via POST method.
2. Your current query is open to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)
3. Your value must be enclosed in quotes. Now it translates to `.. WHERE user_email = joe@anymail.com` *and* that is SQL syntax error.

So your code should look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = %s";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query, $email));
```

Comment: As a follow-up question, Does the keyword "prepare" in the function prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: @JohnKeidel It's not keyword. It's function call. And yes, when using prepared statements there is SQL injection eliminated. Read more about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html